# socket.io nodeJs angularjs one to one chat

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm new to NodeJs. Now I'm trying socket.io. I want to build website like Zopim(https://www.zopim.com/). Now I'm struggling with : client(A) should get helpline from one admin only and to prevent other admins to chat with client(A).
This is server.js

```
  var app = require('express')();
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  var mysql = require("mysql");
  var http = require('http').Server(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(http);
  app.use(require("express").static('data'));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
  }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  /* Creating MySQL connection.*/
  var con  = mysql.createPool({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database :'Chat_tryout'
   });
  var insertRecord = 'Insert into mytable(socketid,receiver,message)value(?,?,?)';
  app.get("/",function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
var msg={};
io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log(socket.id + "connected");

socket.on('message',function(msg){
console.log('user' +this.id+ 'sent message"'+ msg +'"');
    //console.log(" admin id " + io.sockets.connected[socketid]);

con.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
var message=msg;
var socketid=" ";
con.query( insertRecord,[socketid,socket.id,msg], function(err, res) {  
if(err){
    console.log("error:" + err);
}else
    console.log ("inserted"+ socket.id +"message"+ msg);
    //res.end(``);
});
});
app.post('/get_data', function (req, res) {
var msg=req.body.name;
var toid = req.body.toid;
//var socketid = this.socket.sessionid;
//console.log(socketid);
console.log(toid);

io.to(toid).emit('mymessage',msg);
con.getConnection(function(err,connection){
var message=msg;
con.query( insertRecord,[socketid,toid,msg], function(err, res) {   
if(err){
    console.log("error:" + err);
}else
    console.log ( "inserted "+ socket.id +" message "+ msg);
});
});
});
}); 
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
console.log('client socketio disconnect!');
});

app.get('/api/getalldata', function(req,res){
con.getConnection(function(err,connection){
con.query( 'select * from mytable', function(err, rows) {   
if(err){
    console.log("error:" + err);
}else
    console.log ("success");
    res.json(rows);
});   
    }); 
});

});
http.listen(8080,function(){
console.log("Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
});
```

Index.html :
(ADMIN PAGE)

```
<html ng-app="sample">
 <head>
<title>Connecting Node.js app to MySql</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('sample',[]);
    app.controller('sample', function ($scope,$http,$timeout) { 
                $scope.data_server={};
                $scope.socketid={};         
     var TypeTimer;                
     var TypingInterval = 1000;
     $scope.keyup = function() {
            $timeout.cancel(TypeTimer);
            TypeTimer=$timeout( function(){ get_data(); }, TypingInterval);
        };

        $scope.keydown = function(){
            $timeout.cancel(TypeTimer);
        };

        function get_data(){
            var name=$scope.name;
            var toid = $scope.toid;
            $http.post('/get_data',{name:name,toid:toid}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // $scope.data_server=data;
            }).error(function(data, status) {
                //alert("Connection Error");
            });
        } 


    $scope.getalldata = function(){
            $http.get('/api/getalldata')
    .success(function(data) {
        $scope.data_server = data;
       // console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
    });
      };
    });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="sample">
<div class="container">
  <div id="name-group" class="form-group">
  <h2>ADMIN</h2>
  <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="name"  placeholder="Type here and check the Title in Tab"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="toid" ng-keyup="keyup()" ng-keydown="keydown()" ng-blur="blur()"  ng-change="change()"/>
    {{toid}}
    <br/>
  </div>
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover"ng-repeat="data in data_server" >
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
     <td>{{data.receiver}}</td>
     <td>{{data.message}}</td>
    <!-- <td><input type="text" value="{{data.receiver}}"><td> 
      <td><input type="text" ng-model="reply" ng-keyup="submit()"></td>-->
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
  <div class="rows">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="data" >
        <!---{{ data_server}}--->
        <hr/>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="data_server.length == 0"  >
        <div class="alert alert-info" >
          <p class="text-center" >
            Sorry, Right now we don't have any results for you.  
          </p >
        </div >
      </div >
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rows">
 <button class="btn btn primary" ng-click="getalldata()">Get Messages</button>
   <div class="form-row form-last-row">   
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
 var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
 socket.on('message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
```

I'm having html front end for client where they emit and receive messages using:

```
 var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8080");
  $('form').submit(function(){
  socket.emit('message', $('#message').val());
  $('#message').val('');
  return false;
  });
  socket.on('mymessage', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
```

Comment: Any sample of code? Or you want ready solution?

Comment: How can we help when we cant see any code? And read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry ..could you help me